# variable scope in R tryCatch block: is <<- necessary to change local variable defined before tryCatch?

Tags: r, exception, scope

Consider the following code:

```
test1 <- "a"
test2 <- "a"
tryCatch(stop(), error= function(err){
  print(test1)
  print(test2)
  test1 <- "b"
  test2 <<- "b"
})
```

Result:

```
print(test1)
[1] "a"
print(test2)
[1] "b"
```

The value of variable test1 is visible within the tryCatch block, but changing it with "<-" operator does not affect its value outside the tryCatch block.

If a new value is assigned with <<- it has the desired effect. Why?

Is using the <<- operator within the tryCatch block a recommended way to change the value of a local variable outside this block? Could there be some unexpected sideffects?

EDIT: Based on a Bernhard answer, does the following code make up for the right approach to this problem?

```
test1 <- "a"
test2 <- "a"
new_values<-tryCatch(
  {
    print("hello")
    stop()
  }
, error= function(err){
  # I want to change the test1 and test 2 variables to "b" only if error occurred.
  test1 <- "b"
  test2 <- "b"
  return(list(test1=test1,test2=test2))
})
if (is.list(new_values))
{
  test1<-new_values$test1
  test2<-new_values$test2
}
```

Result:

```
> print(test1)
[1] "b"
> print(test2)
[1] "b"
```

Comment: It's technically in an anonymous function called when the error condition arises. All traditional [scoping rules](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping) apply. While `<<-` is heavily cautioned against, it is a tool provided by R to be used judiciously. It's often needed when writing packages and should be either heavily commented or avoided in normal analyses/scripts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The '<<-' is made for side effects that do not belong to R. Use it never, or only if memory or speed force you to do so. A block has it's own scope and if you want to give data from within a block to the 'outside' environement, that there is return() for that task:

```
test2 <- "a"

test2 <- tryCatch(stop(), error= function(err){
  somevariable <- "b"
  return(somevariable)
})
```

This makes it clear to everyone, that toplevel test2 is set to "a" and then, that toplevel test2 is set to something else. With '<<-' it happens easily, that some function changes toplevel test2 and someone wonders, why toplevel test2 has been changed at all. Just don't <<-.

If there is a need to return more than one result, return a list or an object of the results.

EDIT: The OP has pointed out that you need to be carefull with the return statements, as they do not only end the current block, but also the current function. A possible solution is, to run the computations in functions instead of simple blocks. The following example should illustrate this:

```
safediv <- function(a, b){
    normalDo <- function(a, b){
        return(list(value=a/b, message=NULL))
    }
    exceptionalDo <- function(err){
        return(list(value=NaN, message="caught an error! Change global variable?"))
    }
    results <- tryCatch(normalDo(a, b), error=exceptionalDo)
    print("safediv is still running after the returns within the functions.")
    return(results)
}

# try it out  
safediv(5, 3)
safediv(5, 0)
safediv(5, "a")
```

Comment: One thing is not clear to me regarding this solution. If there is for example any print() output in the body of the tryCatch block and no error occurs, it gets returned into the test2 variable. If an error occurs, the value of test2 variable is set by the error function. The "outside" has thus to somehow parse the test2 variable to distinguish whether no error occurred and it contains a copy of the print output that can be discarded, or an error occurred, and this change needs to be propagated to the "outside" variables.

Comment: I edited my question with an attempted complete solution based on your advice and my earlier comment. Is it right in your opinion?

Comment: This looks right. I would probably omit the `if(is.list(..))` part and instead return a list with apropriate values in both cases/blocks, but this may only be me.

Comment: In my original design, I did not want the tryCatch block to return anything. Another problem is that if you try to run the code with the stop() statement and with multiple print statements in the body, you will see that the the value of "new_values" after a run with no errors is the argument of the last print statement.

Comment: You can stick with the original design and the if(...) expression, just finish the first block with a `return()`, which will return a `NULL` instead of whatever has been printed or calculated last in the block. You can then check , whether some error was caught with `if(!is.null(new_values))` instead of the less "speaking" `if(is.list(new_values))`.

Comment: Berhnard this suggestion looked promising, but it does not seem to work if the `tryCatch` block is included in a  function as in my case (not depicted in the example above). In this case, a `return()` statement inside the `tryCatch` block will exit not only the `tryCatch` block, but also the embedding function. Hence we get the following inconsistent behaviour:  code after the `tryCatch` block will not be executed when there is no error, but the code will be executed if there is an error and the return statement appears within the error handling function.

Comment: Good point, tomas. I think the solution is probably to put the computation into a function, so that return() does it's job again. I have added an example on how to declare two functions within an function and call tryCatch with these functions.

Comment: This really needs more upvotes, I've been struggling with error handling in R for a while now and this works perfectly but is not described in any tutorials I have found