# tryCatch block in R, change value of outer variable

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

Here is my code. It produces infinite loop, because value of `something` variable does not change within captured error. Is it supposed to be this way? How can I fix it so that value of `something` changes to `FALSE`?

```
something <- TRUE
counter <- 1
while(something){
  print(counter)  
  tryTest = tryCatch(
    {
      arima(rep(1,3), order = c(1,0,0))
    }, 
    warning = function(w) {

      print('this is warning')
      print(w)
    },
    error = function(e) {
      something <- FALSE
      print('this is error')
      print(e)
    },
    finally = {}
  )
  counter <- (counter +1)
}
```

Comment: Define your warning function as:  `warning = function(w) {
      something <<- FALSE
      print('this is warning')
      print(w)
    } ` ,where "<<-" - *"This operator assigns the variable to the parent scope. It first looks for the variable in the parent scope and if it can’t find one then it creates a new one in the parent scope."*  - http://www.studytrails.com/r/core/assignmentoperator/

Comment: @nadizan, I just tried it and it does not work, still infinite loop

Comment: @nadizan the problem with your suggestion is that the parent scope of the lambda is still inside the tryCatch function and is not the outer scope.

Comment: As a side note. On error, the return value of the error function is returned by `tryCatch` on error. you could always use that to stop your loop. Condition on `tryTest` being non NULL to continue your loop. Just make sure to return something non null on a warning.

Comment: @user1700890, this works completely fine for me. `something <- TRUE
counter <- 1
while(something){
  print(counter)  
  tryTest = tryCatch(
    {
      arima(rep(1,3), order = c(1,0,0))
    }, 
    warning = function(w) {
      something <<- FALSE
      print('this is warning')
      print(w)
    },
    error = function(e) {
      something <- FALSE
      print('this is error')
      print(e)
    },
    finally = {}
  )
  counter <- (counter +1)
}`

Comment: @nadizan you are right. Thank you! Funny how I wrote about catching error, but you put code into warning block. This arima generates both error and warning, and if you add `something <<-FALSE` to error block, it would not work. This is I guess a bit different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391287/trycatch-block-in-r-returning-variable?noredirect=1#comment83770717_48391287

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482937/variable-scope-in-r-trycatch-block-is-necessary-to-change-local-variable-de

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because the environment of `something` in the outer code is different from the environment of `something` in your lambda:

```
function(e) {
    something <- FALSE
    print('this is error')
    print(e)
}
```

So setting `something <- FALSE` in your lambda actually sets a different `something` then in the outer code. To fix this you can either 1) make `something` a global variable or 2) create an environment to use `something` in.

1)

```
assign("something", TRUE, env=globalenv())
```

to set the variable and

```
get("something", env=globalenv())
```

to access the variable.

You can also set `something` inside your lambda in the same way:

```
assign("something", FALSE, env=globalenv())
```

or

2)

First create a new variable:

```
env=new.env()
```

Then set and access your variable in a similar way as before:

```
assign("something", TRUE, env=env)
get("something", env=env)
```

You can assign `something` inside your lambda with:

```
assign("something", FALSE, env=env)
```

Using `env` is possible because R copies variables to child environments. However if you set a variable in a child environment (like when you did `somethi