# R tryCatch in the loop - skip missing values and create a DF showing what was skipped

Tags: r, try-catch

I use a loop to import and bind together a number of Excel files named like "File_ij.xlsx" where i can be from 1 to 4 and j from 1 to 3. However i=3 or j = 2 do not exist, so I have 6 files altogether. That's why I'm using the tryCatch to skip the missing files and display the error message. The code below does what I want. But except for importing, I also want to create a dataframe that records the mising combinations of i and j. And this does not work as I expected. Could anyone tell me why? The code is as follows:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame() # empty DF for storing imported data
missing_df <- data.frame(i = numeric(), j = numeric()) # empty DF for storing information about missing records

for (i in 1:4){
  
  for (j in 1:3) {
    
    tryCatch({
      
      out <- read_xlsx(paste0("C:\\test\\File_", i, j, ".xlsx"))
      df <- bind_rows(df, out)
      
    },
    
    error = function(e) {
      
      message(paste0("The following do not exist: i = ", i, ", j = ", j)) # this works fine, message is displayed
      missing_df <- bind_rows(missing_df, data.frame(i = i, j = j)) # This doesn't work as expected, rows are not appended to the DF
      
    }
    )
    
  }
}
```

Comment: my best guess this has to do with the scope of the error function. Probably your `missing_df` is somewhere, just not in your Global Environment. An easy test would be to use the global assignment operator`<<-` for assignment inside the error function, but I think this is not safe and not elegant. See this post for better options! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482937/variable-scope-in-r-trycatch-block-is-necessary-to-change-local-variable-de

Comment: @uke Thanks, indeed it was the problem with the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General Scoping

This has somehting to do with scoping. In case an error is thrown a the error handler **function** is called, which keeps track about its own variables, **even** if they bear the same name as a variable in the global environment. This example illustrates the idea:

```r
a <- 1
f <- function() {
  cat("Before a is defined in the function it takes the value from global:", a, "\n")
  a <- 2
  cat("After a is defined in the function it takes the value from local:", a, "\n")
}
f()
# Before a is defined in the function it takes the value from global: 1 
# After a is defined in the function it takes the value from local: 2 
cat("After the function is called we only see the global scope:", a, "\n")
# After the function is called we only see the global scope: 1
```

You can assign values in the global environment from within a function using `<<-`, but usually it is best to avoid this pattern:

```r
a <- 1
g <- function() {
  a <<- 2
}
print(a)
# [1] 1
g() ## changes a on global scope
print(a)
# [1] 2
```

---

### `tryCatch`

Within `tryCatch` the same idea applies. The main code is evaluated in the **global** scope (that is we can modify variables within **global** scope without `<<-`), but within the error handler (which is in fact a **function**) we need to use `<<-` to assign on the global sope:

```r
even <- list()
even2 <- list()
odd <- list()
odd_bad <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    tryCatch({
      stopifnot("i * j must be even" = i * j %% 2 == 0)
      ## works because this code is evaluated on global scope
      even2 <- c(even2, list(c(i, j))) 
      even <<- c(even, list(c(i, j)))
    }, error = function(err) {
      ## does not work creates a local version of odd_bad which is later discarded
      odd_bad <- c(odd_bad, list(c(i, j)))
      odd <<- c(odd, list(c(i, j)))
    })
  }
}

length(even)
# [1] 2
length(even2)
# [1] 2
length(odd)
# [1] 4
length(odd_bad)
# [1] 0
```

### Better Pattern Avoiding Global Assignment

Because assigning variables on global scope via `<<-` should be used with care, a better solution would be to return an element from both the main code as well as the error handler amended with a flag (e.g. the class) with which we can then later easily filter good and bad results. This avoids global assignment altogether:

```r
res <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    res <- c(res, 
      tryCatch({
        stopifnot("i * j must be even" = i * j %% 2 == 0)
        list(structure(list(c(i, j)), class = "good"))
      }, error = function(err) {
        list(structure(list(c(i, j)), class = "bad"))
      })
     )
  }
}

Filter(\(e) inherits(e, "good"), res) ## all good results
Filter(\(e) inherits(e, "bad"), res)  ## all badd results
```